# PHP Mysqli database connection pooling to avoid maximum user count

Tags: php, mysqli, connection-pooling

I surfed on Internet for past two days to create the DB pooling by PHP, but not yet achieved. I'm using PHP and MySQLi. We bought the mysqli db with 15 Maximum user connection. I want to pool the db connection to avoid the new connection. I used `persistent` as well as `mysqli_connect`. but I don't feel much different both are creating the new connection since other user already logged in. I was trying this function to get `DB` connection.

```
 <?php
function getConnection(){
    if ($connect){
        return $connect;
    }else{
        $connect = new mysqli('p:xxxx','yyy','zzz','aaaa');
        return $connect;
        if(mysqli_connect_errno($connect))
        {
            echo "Server Busy";
        }
    }
}
 ?>
```

But above function only returns the else part. Please suggest me how to handle this. Thanks in advance. For now I'm killing the process which are in sleep mode to reduce the probability of increasing DB connection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no connection pooling in PHP.

The persistent connection you are trying to use (that "p:" bit) is **the most sure way** to hit the maximum connection number, so get rid of it immediately.

15 concurrent connections is, actually,  A LOT. Simply optimize your queries, so a typical connection would last 0.1 second, which would mean 150 concurrently executed PHP scripts which is like 1500 users on-line.

Also, you need to add

```
static $connect;
```

as the first line in your function, or is will create the new connection every time it is called, which is the actual reason why you are getting this error.

```
<?php
function getConnection(){
    static $connect;

    if (!$connect){
        mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
        $connect = new mysqli('xxxx','yyy','zzz','aaaa');
        $connect->set_charset('utf8mb4');
    }
    return $connect;
}
```

Better yet, get rid of this function at all, have a separate file with the mysql connection code, and then use the `$connect` variable all around your code. See my article about [mysqli connect](https://phpdelusions.net/mysqli/mysqli_connect) for the details.

Comment: Could you explain a little more how you got to the 1500 number?

Comment: Thet's just quite a rough estimation. Assuming every user requests the site once every 10 seconds, it will make 150 requests per second.

Comment: Hi My Common Sense, sry for the late reply. so by following this method do i need to close the connection? once the query got executed

Comment: @Aroon **never**. Just never close the connection. Php will close it for you all right.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I will try this and let you know.

Comment: Just for more information, this is a design pattern known as Singleton. If you really want to, you sure can manage a connection pool by hand but there are no advantage.

Answer (score 0):

This is not how it works. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24902615/connection-pooling-vs-persist-connection-mysqli). MySQLi will select one of available connections when you execute `new mysqli('p:...` The connection is persistent, not the PHP object.

```
function getConnection(){
    mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
    return (new mysqli('p:xxxx','yyy','zzz','aaaa'));
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the heads up... I will try that and let you know whether it is solved my problem or not

Comment: I have  a question. above is the all that I need to put in that file?

Comment: Yes. A side comment: I do not think you need persistent connections at all. You should revalidate whether you really need to do it.

Comment: I tried the above function. but for each user it is taking one connection

Comment: What do you mean each user? Do you mean for each http request or are you using multiple DB users?

Comment: when I trigger a.php the connection get hiked by 1. at the same time the other person also triggered a.php, the db connection increased by 1.. so totally two connections consumed

Comment: Persistent connection is not going to help you in this case then. You still need a separate MySQL connection for each thread. If you have 15 or more concurrent HTTP requests which all open the MySQLi connection then you will reach that limit anyway.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197728/discussion-between-aroon-and-dharman).