# MySQL number of connections not increasing

Tags: mysql, tomcat, database-performance

I have set my MySQL `max_connections` variable to 1024. I'm using a connection pool to connect to the database.

```
  <Resource type="javax.sql.DataSource"
                        name="jdbc/testDB"
                        factory="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory"
                        driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
                        url="jdbc:mysql://192.168.2.110:3306/testdb?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull&amp;autoReconnect=true"
                        username="test"
                        password="test" 
                        initialSize="10"
                        maxActive="1000"
                        maxWait="60000"                          
                        maxIdle="50"
                        removeAbandonedTimeout="300"
                        removeAbandoned="true"
                        minIdle="10" />
```

But when I'm running my application, application threads are blocked for database connections. So while my application is running I execute the following query:

```
SHOW STATUS WHERE `variable_name` = 'Threads_connected';
```

It gives me answer of 131. Shouldn't it increase until reaching `max_connections` parameter?

Comment: So is there a way to see how many database connections open ?

Comment: Read https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/connection-threads.html

Comment: I think u had it right with dumping the variable

Comment: So is there way to increase my connection pool size?

Answer (score 0):

The `STATUS` value `Max_used_connections` is the highwater mark for `Threads_connected`.  You will probably find it to be 1000.  The "131" was the then *current* number of connections.

There is one extra connection reserved for `SUPER` users to get in.  That would be seen in Max_used_connections = 1025 when max_connections is 1024.

Comment: How does this address the question or permanently change the setting.

Comment: `SET GLOBAL` will work until mysql stops.  Change `my.cnf` to have it take effect next time mysql starts.  It is unclear whether/how the OP changed things.

Comment: Sorry to use your own words on you. Carry on as u were

Answer (score -1):

```
Show variables like 'max_connections';

Set global max_connections=250;
```

Comment: Btw max can be exceed by a bit for super connections as per manual

Comment: As for pooling, care must be taken to minimize time of use and do a release. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9736188/mysql-persistent-connection-vs-connection-pooling

Comment: But when I have threaddump and check it has 166 number of (a com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection) exceptions. Any idea?

Comment: Downvoted because it does not address the question.  Nor does it permanently change the setting.