# How PHP handles MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql

Well I was wondering how PHP handles MySQL connection?

For example, on our web-server there are index.php, info.php.
Each one of them has to connect to a database and retrieve some data.
That means that on both of those files I got to make `mysqli_connect` or could I have a "global" connection?
For every client, that visit my website, PHP create new connection?

So one case scenario might be on index.php there is a select query and at same time there are 10000 visitors on my website. so there will be created 10000 connections?

Comment: What's worse - 1000 connections with a single request, or a single connection with 1000 requests?

Comment: @MacroMan That's part of what OP is asking :P

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9736188/mysql-persistent-connection-vs-connection-pooling

Answer (score 0):

PDO allows you to create pool of connections to avoid the overhead of establishing a new connection every time a script needs to talk to a database. Please check for more detail: http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.connections.php